# How to create data using Typescript Sequelize model without passing in an id

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Typescript and looking for a way to run `Course.create()` but can't avoid needing to specify an `id` field just to run the `.create()` method. Here is the Course model:

```
import { DataTypes, Model, Optional } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index';


interface CourseAttributes {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
};

/*
  We have to declare the CourseCreationAttributes to
  tell Sequelize and TypeScript that the property id,
  in this case, is optional to be passed at creation time
*/
interface CourseCreationAttributes
    extends Optional<CourseAttributes, 'id'> { }

interface CourseInstance
    extends Model<CourseAttributes, CourseCreationAttributes>,
    CourseAttributes {
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}


const Course = db.sequelize.define<CourseInstance>(
    'Course',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        name: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        city: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        state: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        country: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
    }
);



export default Course;
```

**Note** that I would like to pass in this data *without* the id. I don't want to have to include an id when I make a POST request. But no matter what I do, I always seem to get an error `Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

```
{
    "name": "Pebble Beach",
    "city": "San Diego",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "US"
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'll need to do two things:

- specify a `defaultValue` key on the model.
- use a separate package (or custom function) to generate the UUID for `defaultValue`.

The following code example is inspired from [issue 13912 on the Sequelize Github repo.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13912#issuecomment-1006713984).

```
import { Uuid4 } from 'id128'

id: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: () => Uuid4.generate().toCanonical(),
},
```